Resilience4j RateLimiter allowing too many requests in first period
Issue & my solution
The issue seems to be that the first period is not respected and the RateLimiter allows through more requests than configured.
To replicate the issue or use the "solution", just comment/uncomment the call to "warmup" inside the "rateLimiter" bean.
Note that the solution is more of an attempt of a solution as even with that it seems to sometimes result in wait period between 1st and 2nd period being slightly too short.
MyBeans
@Configuration
public class MyBeans {
    private static void warmup(final RateLimiter rateLimiter) {
        final int limitForPeriod = rateLimiter.getRateLimiterConfig().getLimitForPeriod();
        for (int i = 0; i < limitForPeriod; i++) {
            Mono.empty()
                    .transformDeferred(RateLimiterOperator.of(rateLimiter))
                    .block();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public RateLimiter rateLimiter() {
        final RateLimiterConfig config = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
                .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(15))
                .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .limitForPeriod(5)
                .build();
        final RateLimiter rateLimiter = new AtomicRateLimiter("limiter", config);
        warmup(rateLimiter);
        return rateLimiter;
    }
}

MyClient
    @Service
    public class MyClient {

        private final RateLimiter rateLimiter;
    
        public MyClient(final RateLimiter rateLimiter) {
            this.rateLimiter = rateLimiter;
        }
    
        private Mono<String> getDataFrom() {
            return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
                final Instant now = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis());
                final String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                final String text = "making request...";
                System.out.printf("%s - %s: %s%n", now, threadName, text);
                return "data:" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100);
            });
        }
    
        public Mono<String> getData() {
            return getDataFrom()
                .transformDeferred(RateLimiterOperator.of(rateLimiter));
        }
    }

For completeness, here is the handler & router as well.
DataHandler
@Component
public final class DataHandler {

    private final MyClient myClient;

    public DataHandler(MyClient myClient) {
        this.myClient = myClient;
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getData(final ServerRequest request) {
        final Instant now = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        final String text = "/data called...";
        System.out.printf("%s - %s: %s%n", now, threadName, text);
        return myClient.getData()
                .flatMap(l -> ServerResponse.ok()
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(l));
    }
}

DataRouter
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DataRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getData(final DataHandler dataHandler) {
        final RequestPredicate request = RequestPredicates.GET("/data")
                .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        return RouterFunctions.route(request, dataHandler::getData);
    }
}

Then I run many requests in parallel to the service, I used both postman runner and this command:
seq 1 80 | xargs -Iname -P12  curl "http://localhost:8088/data"

Output
2024-06-26T19:04:12.375Z - parallel-5: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.375Z - parallel-4: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.375Z - parallel-8: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.375Z - parallel-1: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.375Z - parallel-3: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.380Z - parallel-2: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.380Z - parallel-5: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.380Z - parallel-4: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.380Z - parallel-6: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.380Z - parallel-7: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.381Z - parallel-3: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.381Z - parallel-1: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.417Z - parallel-2: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.418Z - parallel-2: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.446Z - parallel-2: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.446Z - parallel-4: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.451Z - parallel-8: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.451Z - parallel-7: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:12.452Z - parallel-1: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.376Z - parallel-8: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.376Z - parallel-7: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.377Z - parallel-6: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.377Z - parallel-5: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.377Z - parallel-4: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.412Z - parallel-6: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.412Z - parallel-1: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.412Z - parallel-7: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.412Z - parallel-8: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:19.412Z - parallel-5: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:29.373Z - parallel-3: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:29.374Z - parallel-1: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:29.373Z - parallel-5: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:29.373Z - parallel-6: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:29.380Z - parallel-3: making request...
2024-06-26T19:04:29.405Z - parallel-7: /data called...
2024-06-26T19:04:29.405Z - parallel-8: /data called...

As you can see, it runs at seconds 12, 19 and 29.
Expected output would be something like 12, 22 and 32.
Questions

Am I doing something very strange or is this a bug?
My solution "works" sometimes, but not always, any idea why?
Is there a way to solve for this issue?

Update 1
Forgot to include my dependencies.
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

...

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring boot starters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For jakarta.validation package -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Rate limiter -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.resilience4j/resilience4j-ratelimiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-ratelimiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required for RateLimitOperator -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.resilience4j/resilience4j-reactor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
...

